# Need some help understanding jQuery code - Function within a function

Tags: javascript, jquery

I need some help understanding some JavaScript code. Here is the code:

`MyVar.js:`

```
var MyVar = (function($){

  var _this;
  ...
  
  function myVar()
  {
        _this = this;
  }
  
  myVar.prototype.test()
  {
    console.log("Hello World");
  }
  ...
})(window.jQuery);
```

From an ASP.NET view:

```
var myVar = new MyVar();
myVar.test();
```

I've tried running this code in a [JSFiddle example](https://jsfiddle.net/n4z8acux/1/), but I get an error. How exactly does this code work?

Edit:

This is the error I am getting: `Uncaught TypeError: myVar.prototype.test is not a function`.

Comment: 1) What is the error? 2) Why do you thiink this code _would_ work - ie, where did you get it from?

Comment: The construct `myvar.func() \n { }` is the same as `myvar.func(); {}` - the `;` is implied by the newline after the `()` - so you get an error that `func()` is not defined (or in your case `.prototype` is not defined on `myvar`.  Without the newline, you get `"Unexpected token '{'"`

Comment: @Jamiec 1) I updated my question 2) I have edited the question from where I am calling the function from

Comment: You miss my point, youve copied that code from somewhere, and you dont understand it because you've (I think) made a mistake in copying it.  Where did it come from?

Comment: @Meeth But you still haven't answered the second question, Why do you think this code would work? Where did you get it from or did you create it yourself?

Comment: "How exactly does this code work?" — As you've demonstrated: It doesn't.

Comment: Okay, so my manager got back to me and said there is a lot going on under the hood. I should just get a basic understanding of the logic.

Comment: There _is no logic here_ - it doesn't work!

Comment: @Jamiec He said it has something to do with closures. This code was written by someone else. It definitely works, but there is a lot going on here. Maybe I'm just omitting some critical stuff.

Comment: I suggest you ask him, because we cant help you unless we know what it's trying to do here. You need some _working_ code if you want someone to explain to you what is going on

Comment: @Jamiec I will definitely need to ask him about it

Comment: @Meeth in case it helps here are the docs on closures: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Closures